# how to get the url controller?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem

in my views.py have

```
def custom_proc(request):
    return {
        'user': request.user,
    }
```

I need to analyze the current url in custom_proc. the problem is that I do not understand how to get this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it by request.path:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following function:

```
def giveAResult(request):

      myUser = request.user

      context = {
         'myUser': myUser,
      }
      return render(request, "path.html", context)
```

You can use: `render`, `HttpResponse`, `render_to_response` and so on. ([see link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/))